# OOJS call other method

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var Lines = function(startXCon, endXCon,startYCon, endYCon)
{


    this.drawCurve = function()
    {


    }
    this.changeCurve = function(e)
    {
        //how can I call drawCurve from this method
    }

}
```

The comment in my code explains the problem. Is this possible or are all methods private?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var Lines = function(startXCon, endXCon,startYCon, endYCon){   
  var self = this; // store this as a variable to use in nested function
  this.drawCurve = function(){}
  this.changeCurve = function(e){
   self.drawCurve(); //now call this.drawCurve()
  }
}
```